# Powershell - VMWare Remove 'Orphaned' VMs, and Register Back

Tags: powershell, vmware

Ok so I'm editing the post.

Figured out something here, but still straggling with the 'get/save' path of the VMX and the VM name.

this is the script:

```
$vCenter = "vc"
$vCUser = "user"
$vCPW = "pass"

Connect-VIServer $vCenter -User $vCUser -Password $vCPW -Force

$ResourcePool = "hostname"

$VMHost = Get-VMHost -Name $ResourcePool | Get-VM -Name * | ?{$_.ExtensionData.Runtime.ConnectionState -eq "orphaned"} | Select-Object Name, @{N = 'VMX'; E = { $_.ExtensionData.Summary.Config.VmPathName}}

Remove-VM -VM $VMHost.Name -Confirm:$false

New-VM -Name $VMHost.Name -ResourcePool $ResourcePool -VMFilePath $VMHost.VMX

Disconnect-VIServer -Server $vCenter -Force -Confirm:$false
```

but when I run the script, its doesn't save the VMHost.Name to register back the VM from the path if there are more than 1 orphaned VM on the host.
any ideas how to save the VMHost.Name after the Remove-VM ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
just did

- find the orphaned VMs
- get/save the path of the VMX file
- use Remove-VM (without the DeletePermanently switch) to unregister them
- register them with New-VM and the VMFilePath parameter using the VMX path you saved in step 2
  as suggested on another side